# Losing global value in function

Tags: javascript

wonder if anyone can help.

bascially In javascript I am trying to grab the image sizes of an image before it has loaded to the page, so I can resize some thumbnails on the fly in a gallery.

The path in works fine, the preloader works fine, and I can see the width & height is being grabbed in the getWidthAndHeight function.

My problem is, I'm trying to assign this to a global variable to use in other functions, but the global variable is lost outside of the getWidthAndHeight function. (I declared the global var at the start of the file eg var gwidth)

I have notcied thought however it all works when I stuck the alert(gwidth) in there ! obvioulsy I don't the alert box firing off - any ideas why this only works when the alert is in there, and why the global could be losing its value when the alert is disabled ?

Thanks

```
function getWidthAndHeight() {
    gwidth = this.width;
    alert(gwidth);
    gheight = this.height;  
    return true;
}
function loadFailure() {
    alert("'" + this.name + "' failed to load.");
    return true;
}




function getImgSize(gim_imgSrc)
{

var myImage = new Image();

myImage.name = gim_imgSrc;
myImage.onload = getWidthAndHeight;
myImage.onerror = loadFailure;
myImage.src = gim_imgSrc;

getWidthAndHeight(myImage);
alert("width is" + gwidth);
alert(testglobal);

return gwidth;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you declare the global variables in the global scope? It's also easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't working because the image onload event fires asynchronously (i.e. potentially after you've returned `gwidth`). It's working when you alert because you're stalling execution for a few seconds, thus giving the image time to load.

You can try passing a callback function:

```
function getImgSize(gim_imgSrc, callback) {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = gim_imgSrc;
    myImage.onload = function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
        callback(gwidth);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Im looking into this but having a few issues at the mo; I'm getting undefined when I run this at the moment. Should it be ok calling this callback multiple times (bascially Im using jcarousel and calling each element somewhere before) but this is how Im calling each instance; var pp_imageWidth = getImgSize(pp_fullpath); thanks

Comment: @mro Are you passing a callback function to `getImgSize`? What is undefined?

Comment: @emmet apologies, I'm a little new to this;I think part of the problem is I don't fully undertsand callbacks and how to implement, your code calls the getWidthAndHeight fine, but the alert spits out undefined from that function. I was wondering if I needed to update how I call getImgSize, which at the moment is as it was;var pp_imageWidth = getImgSize(pp_fullpath); thanks

Comment: @mro You need to alert from inside the callback like this: `getImgSize("foo.png", function(width) { alert(width); });`

Comment: Thanks, I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere, maybe in the calling pp_imageWidth = getImgSize(pp_fullpath); I'm going to read up on callbacks I think, and give this another go !

Answer (score 3):

[Globals are evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Use [closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html).

```
var getImgSize = (function() {
    var gwidth, gheight;
    function getWidthAndHeight() {
        gwidth = this.width;
        alert(gwidth);
        gheight = this.height;  
        return true;
    }
    function loadFailure() {
        alert("'" + this.name + "' failed to load.");
        return true;
    }

    return function (gim_imgSrc) {
        var myImage = new Image();

        myImage.name = gim_imgSrc;
        myImage.onload = getWidthAndHeight;
        myImage.onerror = loadFailure;
        myImage.src = gim_imgSrc;

        getWidthAndHeight(myImage);
        alert("width is" + gwidth);
        alert(testglobal);

        // this probably won't work
        return gwidth;
    };
})();
```

There's also a problem in that image loading is asynchronous (i.e. when `getImgSize` returns, the image may not have loaded). Any code that depends on the return value of `getImgSize` should instead be turned into a callback.

```
function getImgSize(gim_imgSrc, didLoad, didntLoad) {
    var myImage = new Image();

    myImage.name = gim_imgSrc;
    myImage.onload = function() {
        // you don't really need this
        //getWidthAndHeight.call(myImage); 
        // the following should be enough
        return didLoad(myImage, myImage.width, myImage.height);
    };
    myImage.onerror = function() {
        return didntLoad(myImage);
    }
    myImage.src = gim_imgSrc;
}
```